# adding multiple fax lines into a server

Tags: fax

I need a little help with some research.  We currently wrote an application to receive incoming fax.  This is then converted to an email and saved as an image file using Snappy Fax.  What we need to know now is….  How will we get multiple fax (phone) lines into the server?  What are the best solutions for us to do this with our Pharmacies?  What is stable but cost effective?  Do we need a multi port card, etc?

Comment: How many fax lines are we talking about 2, 4, 24?

Comment: What kind of server? Feel free to provide some relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the Brooktrout line. It looks like it is now owned by www.dialogic.com.

Answer (score 0):

In my research, individual cards go as high as 8 ports.  I have experience with [Perle](http://www.perle.com/products/Multimodem-Cards.shtml) cards on Linux.  The drivers support multiple cards in the PC up to something like 512 ports (which is pretty impossible to hit 8 ports at a time, where you probably only have 4 ports on a server)

You may also want to check out [iFax solutions](http://www.ifax.com/).  They provide enterprise faxing solutions and have links to other [hardware](http://www.ifax.com/shop/hardware.html) that is available.